# How do I select all party members in the tactical map?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I was watching a demo by one of the devs ; in the Tactical map he was just selecting a target, and all party members where told to attack it.

I can only make this happen by selecting party members one at a time and giving them the order...

How can I make all party members attack at once ?

Comment: did you try ctrl+a?

Answer (score 1):

On PC : press <kbd>`↹`</kbd> two times. Your crosshair turns yellow on a enemy, now press <kbd>E</kbd> and your entire party will attack the enemy.

Comment: can you only do this with mouse and keyboard? I kinda like just slouching on my chair to play :), also Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the console you are using, PlayStation or Xbox, you need to either press <kbd>R1</kbd>/<kbd>L1</kbd> together or <kbd>RB</kbd>/<kbd>LB</kbd> together.
This will select the whole party, and if you press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd> (PS or Xbox), the party will all attack the same enemy.

You can also press the bumpers together while you have the radial menu open; Whatever command you choose will be issued to the entire party.

Answer (score -1):

You can attack with your character, and then use the radial menu to order your party to attack your target.

What you're asking for specifically may only be possible with the PC keyboard/mouse controls.